# Have Wiremock write specific call results to file

Tags: xcode, wiremock

We have a need to verify that a few URL's are called during a test run (iOS Simulator) using wiremock.  The desire would be to have wiremock write the requested url to a file in some way during a test.  We would then validate using this file.  Has anyone found a way to extend wiremock in this way?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Post-serve Action](http://wiremock.org/docs/extending-wiremock/#post-serve-actions) to write to a file that you've created. The [ServeEvent](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.github.tomakehurst/wiremock/2.5.0/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/stubbing/ServeEvent.html) contains a reference to the matched request, stub, and response, so you can grab whatever data you need (most likely the `request.url` or `request.absoluteUrl`) and print that to a file.